# Oracle data backfill and foreward fill

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables named as t1 and ids. t1 contains id and data values order by id. while ids has a list of all valid ids. The t1 data has holes and I would like to fill them:

- fill the rows with 1st available data, otherwise
- fill the rows with latest valid data

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72c623/5)

```
create table t1 
(myid int, 
 my_value varchar(10));

insert into t1 values(3, 'Value 3');
insert into t1 values(4, 'Value 4');
insert into t1 values(4, 'Value 5');

create table ids
(
  mids int
);

insert into ids values(1);
insert into ids values(2);
insert into ids values(3);
insert into ids values(4);
insert into ids values(5);
insert into ids values(6);
```

In above example, I would like to have the final result in t1 as:

| myid | my_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 3 |
| 2 | Value 3 |
| 3 | Value 3 |
| 4 | Value 4 |
| 5 | Value 5 |
| 6 | Value 5 |

The merge query I am using below will not filling the table with correct values. I am not able to figure out how to pick the 1st available and/or the last valid value. How should I do?

```
Merge INTO t1
  Using (SELECT ids.mids, t1.values FROM t1 Right JOIN ids ON t1.myid = ids.mids) y
  ON (t1.myid = y.mids)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (myid, my_value)
    VALUES (y.mids, y.values);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72c623/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` and `LEAD` analytic functions within a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO t1 dst
USING (
  SELECT i.mids AS myid,
         t.ROWID AS rid,
         COALESCE(
           my_value,
           LAG(my_value) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY i.mids),
           LEAD(my_value) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY i.mids)
         ) AS my_value
  FROM   ids i
         LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 t
         ON i.mids = t.myid
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (myid, my_value) VALUES (src.myid, src.my_value);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table t1 (myid, my_value) AS
  SELECT 3, 'Value 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Value 4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Value 5' FROM DUAL;

create table ids (mids) AS
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| MYID | MY_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 3 |
| 2 | Value 3 |
| 3 | Value 3 |
| 4 | Value 4 |
| 5 | Value 5 |
| 6 | Value 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GPNiegkQ)